# Limit rows to show with Boolean parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a coulmn and it has 2 different sets of data, one which starts with Letter and followed by number(Ex:A8753426) and another is only Numeric(7655477)
I have created a report and it shows all the rows. I want it to show all rows when end user select to Show with Letters else it should only shows Numeric values.

### Column

A2232322
24343432
12234455
Z1234544

I am using SSRS 2008 to create reports

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try: in datasets filters 
use expression like

```
=iif(isnumeric(left(Fields!yourfield.Value,1)) = 1 ,"number","letter")
```

operator: "="

Value: would be your parameter (should have 2 available values  "number" and "letter")

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my column is of varchar and how would I filter it out based on Number and letter.

Comment: left(field,1)  function returns only the 1st character of the string isnumeric function returns only 1 or 0 (1 for numbers 0 for everything else) so the formula is saying (if first character is a number then display word number else display work letter ( you can use other words as long as your parameters has them too)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i created 2 reports and linked them with the action field so when they want to see Alpha-Numeric values they just need to click on link and it takes them to that report.

Answer (score 1):

created 2 reports and linked them with the action field so when they want to see Alpha-Numeric values they just need to click on link and it takes them to that report